# Have Apache Stop Using Squid

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, squid

I have Apache working with Squid, but I would now like to remove it. I know how to stop Squid, but that stops serving my site.  How can I have Apache stop using Squid?

Comment: Can I ask how you integrated squid with apache? I've searched a lot but haven't found the solution. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to locate and change the Apache [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive in your configuration. This will most likely be in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` (but it could be elsewhere). Change the Listen to

```
Listen 80
```

and save the file. Stop squid and then restart apache and you should be good to go. If this works you'll need to stop squid from starting at the next reboot. You should be able to do this with

```
 update-rc.d -f squid remove
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple yet I had been struggling for a while to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall squid using `apt-get remove --purge squid-package-name` (and run `apt-get clean` for good measure). Edit your Apache configuration files to make sure `httpd` is not listening on the proxy port anymore, but instead listening on standard port 80 (or whatever port you want it listening to). Restart apache.